# How do I go about removing a built-in application on MacOS Catalina 10.15.6?

Tags: macos, mac, sudo, terminal.app, su

Here are the things I've tried...

I'm within `/System/Application`, went into Finder and was able to change permission to custom and have set both Admin/Everyone to Read/Write.

- Disabled SIP
- Became root user
- Mounted - `sudo mount -uw`
- Used `rm -rf` for the unwanted application

The terminal still outputs Read-only system file.

1. Is this something that cannot be worked around?
2. I've read on other forums that this is a restriction of Catalina, if so, would updating to BigSur make the situation worse/better?

Answer (score 0):

Root won't ever help on a Mac. If sudo can't do it, neither can root.

You need to boot from another drive to change a protected folder. On Catalina, this will work until the next update, then it will put them all back again.
On Big Sur this is much harder, as you need to rebuild the SSV structure & set a new good snapshot.

**Best advice…**
***Leave it alone. You'll break something.***

Comment: Why is it that root will not help on Mac? I understand that root has limited privileges when it comes to what can/cannot be changed. 
Please correct me if I'm mistaken, but, I'm assuming that you're referring to booting into a different drive with the same MacOS, so that within Recovery Mode, I would be able to make changes for the main MacOS within that terminal of that secondary drive. 

On BigSur, when you say rebuild, does that mean completely rebuilding the MacOS System boot volume or reinstalling the entirety of the OS?

Comment: Root doesn't help because it has no more privileges than any admin with sudo. To work on the system partition in Catalina you must be booted to something that will not respect the privileges on it. Big Sur has much stronger protection for the system volume, meaning if you try to change it you will break it. https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=3xpv8r2m It's just not worth the effort.

Comment: How does booting into a different drive not respect the security privileges placed on the system partition of Catalina? And what specifically would you have to be booted into?

Comment: It's sounding more & more like you really don't even know how to start this - so please don't. You'll break something. No OS respects the privileges of a non-boot drive, so all you need is to boot from **any** other drive, **any** other OS… though it has to be one that can read & write APFS. i've added emphasis to my answer...

Comment: I understand the risks/exploitation of doing all this. I somewhat know what I'm doing, and I'm doing this out of curiosity. You're right. After reading what you've commented, I won't  act on this. But, I'm curious, what is the worst that could happen if I did? The worst thing I could see happening is reinstalling the entirety of the OS.

Comment: Correct. It's not going to explode or start shooting laser beams at you… yet the severity of the consequence will depend entirely on the time since your last solid, tested, restorable backup. (The number of people who have no solid backup, or one from a year ago or more, makes this a thing to avoid in general.)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to walk me through and explain every detail. I'm far more understanding of the process now than I was like ten hours ago. Happy New Year :)